# How to block Url when user resends from browser in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url, asp.net-core-webapi, block

I want once the Url has been successfully received, after that the user cannot resend the desired URL through the **Inspect** part of the browser and receive the information again.

For example, shown in the first screenshot, the Url called `GetMenu` has been received successfully, but the problem is that the user can resend the same URL and receive the information (shown in the second screenshot), I want the user not to be able to do this.

Is there a solution?

Screenshot #1:

[image]

Screenshot #2:

[image]

Comment: Include some kind of one-time-use parameter  `/url.aspx ?doc-id=123  &one-time-token=12345` and use a database to invalidate the token after one use or after x minutes.  Or: AWS S3 storage has signed URLs for fetching static files, Azure probably has something similar.  You can't block this with client-side scripting.

Comment: Can you give an example as a disposable parameter?@DaveS

Comment: It can be a hash like MD5, a random string, a GUID, stored in a database table.  For fast table lookup and to avoid collisions you might have something like (user-id, url  hash, one-time-token).  For AWS storage API a signed URL is described here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html